# How can I avoid tabbibg into the browser's URL area?

Tags: html, css

My user needs to press tab, not click the mouse, to move between elements on my page.

I don't want the user to end up in the browser's URL box when he is tabbibg around. How can I make the browser's URL box a notab area?

We are hoping to avoid jQuery, and just use html and css.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. It is standard browser behaviour.

Comment: I don't think this is possible...

Comment: It's not possible, and in any case, on what planet would you hope to achieve that with HTML & CSS?

Comment: You can use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/H7DFA/1/ or this http://jsfiddle.net/H7DFA/2/ (btw, javascript will work on 98% of computers)